# how to style a horizontal submenu with nested <ul>

Tags: html, css, menu

I can't figure this out.
How can I style this menu with css. 
I need to style .mainNav2, but the template build the menu like this:

```
<ul class="mainNav1">
   <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
   <li><a class="current level_1" href="#">2</a></li>
   <li>
     <ul class="mainNav2">
       <li><a href="#">a</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">b</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">c</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
</ul>
```

I would like a horizontal menu, with the submenu horizontal under the mainNav1 menu, starting all left, under the first main menu li-item.

the css:

```
ul.mainNav1{list-style-type: none;
margin:0;
padding: 0;}

ul.mainNav1 li{float:left;
display: inline;
margin: 0;  
padding: 0;}

ul.mainNav1 li a{
font-family:'Playfair Display', serif;
font-size:20px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
color:#666;
margin-right:20px;}

ul.mainNav2{position:absolute; width:600px; margin:30px 0 0 -100px;}
ul.mainNav2 li{float:left; background:url(bg-menu.png) repeat;}
ul.mainNav2 li:first-child{border-radius:5px 0 0 5px;}
ul.mainNav2 li:last-child{border-radius:0 5px 5px 0;}
ul.mainNav2 li a{font-size:15px;}
ul.mainNav1 li a { padding:4px 4px 4px 4px; }
ul.mainNav2 li a { padding:4px 4px 4px 14px; }
ul.mainNav3 li a { padding:4px 4px 4px 24px; }
ul.mainNav1 a:hover{color: #f7ccaf; }
ul.mainNav1 a.current { font-style:italic; color:#a7a7a7;}
```

Comment: You should add your CSS to the question.

Comment: got it, wasn't finished ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

Updated to reflect your css.

http://jsfiddle.net/jralvarez28/ezLu0482/3/

```
ul.mainNav1{
position: relative;
list-style-type: none;
margin:0;
padding: 0;}

ul.mainNav1 li{
display: inline-block;
margin: 0;  
padding: 0;}

ul.mainNav1 li a{
font-family:'Playfair Display', serif;
font-size:20px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
color:#666;
margin-right:20px;}

ul.mainNav2{position:absolute; width:600px; top: 100%; left: 0; padding: 0;}
ul.mainNav2 li{float:left; background:url(bg-menu.png) repeat;}
ul.mainNav2 li:first-child{border-radius:5px 0 0 5px;}
ul.mainNav2 li:last-child{border-radius:0 5px 5px 0;}
ul.mainNav2 li a{font-size:15px;}
ul.mainNav1 li a { padding:4px 4px 4px 4px; }
ul.mainNav2 li a { padding:4px 4px 4px 4px; }
ul.mainNav3 li a { padding:4px 4px 4px 24px; }
ul.mainNav1 a:hover{color: #f7ccaf; }
ul.mainNav1 a.current { font-style:italic; color:#a7a7a7;}
```

The trick is

```
ul.mainNav1 {
position: relative;
}

ul.mainNav2 {
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
left: 0;
}
```

This will put `.mainNav2` right under `.mainNav1`

Comment: tnx! I now see your new edits, what you first wrote was the trick! can you explain what you did?

Answer (score 2):

`ul li ul.mainNav2` is the selector.

If you use Chrome or firefox, use the element inspector to find the unique CSS path by right clicking on the html and selecting the option.

Edit: You should really make the question more descriptive. Idk what you mean by a horizontal sub menu.....

Comment: tnx, I got the element, but I can't get it styled properly

Comment: So can you please explain better what you mean when you say a horizontal sub menu? If you're looking for a dropdown you can't really get one without some JS.

Comment: dropdown also very  nice, but when I use that, with hover and .slidetoggle it doesn't work, because the ul is nested, the li that you need to hover is in front.

Comment: like this example http://designvorlage01.jimdo.com/leistungen/submenu-2/ tried to copy the css, but still I do something wrong

Answer (score 0):

I think I have your solution based on what I could understand from your question.

`ul.mainNav2{position:absolute; width:600px; margin:30px 0 0 -100px;}`

change it to

`ul.mainNav2{position:absolute; width:600px; margin:30px 0 0 -125px;}`

Is this what you wanted?

Comment: No, this won't work, it changes the position, but the submenu items of the other menu items, won't start from under the first main item. It only slides it more to the left